# Create YT.Player object from iframe in HTML by passing DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I have an embedded youtube video iframe in my html that I need to stop programatically, but I am unable to set the id of the iframe. Therefore I am trying to create the youtube object by passing the DOM element to the YT.Player constructor rather than the iframe id, as specified in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). I have also appended '?enablejsapi=1' to the end of my iframe src url.

I have loaded the youtube js api at the top of my js file using the following code:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){ console.log('yt api ready'); }
```

After that I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        var player = new YT.Player($('iframe').get(0));
        player.stopVideo();
    });
})
```

I get the output:

```
yt api ready
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopVideo'
```

I'm assuming I'm screwing up the object instantiation somehow, but I don't know how to do this correctly. How do I create a YT.Player object without passing the constructor the iframe id? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to move the stop video call into the player object's ready event. The following changes fixed it for me

Added the following function:

```
function onMyPlayerReady(event) { event.target.stopVideo(); }
```

And changed the yt.player constructor to:

```
new YT.Player($('iframe').get(0), { events: { 'onReady': onMyPlayerReady } });
```

Comment: any chance you could post your complete code? i'm not sure i follow where you are placing the yt.player constructor?  within the click event?